# PrimeNG p-table Lazy loading and Multi Sort - Goes in Loop - Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: primeng, primeng-turbotable

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-p-table-multisort

Config:
`"@angular/cli": "~7.0.2",
"primeng": "7.0.5",`

I have a PrimeNG p-table implemented with lazy loading. Need multi column sort added to it.

Sample code from above Stackblitz link.

`<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="cars1" [lazy]="true" [lazyLoadOnInit]="false" (onLazyLoad)="loadList($event)" sortMode="multiple" [multiSortMeta]="multiSortMeta">`

This works properly if its single sort mode.

Getting error as `ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

It should be a simple implementation but not able to understand what is missing here or this is not supported by PrimeNG.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can someone tell me why the `close` vote?

Comment: your demo don't show any problem ?

Comment: Seriously, no idea how the error stopped. Of course I did update the demo code to explain the problem in detail to @AbhinavKumar today, but it was still showing the error. My only problem now is that the `loadList()` is getting called via `p-table` even though `lazyLoadOnInit` value is set to `false`. I don't want the table to do that. On `pagination` and `sort`, it should but not on `init`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-p-table-multisort

It worked with overriding the PrimeNG `Table` - `sortMultiple` method via prototype chain.

**Old code:**

```
Table.prototype.sortMultiple = function () {
    var _this = this;
    if (this.multiSortMeta) {
        if (this.lazy) {
            this.onLazyLoad.emit(this.createLazyLoadMetadata());
        }
        else if (this.value) {
            if (this.customSort) {
                this.sortFunction.emit({
                    data: this.value,
                    mode: this.sortMode,
                    multiSortMeta: this.multiSortMeta
                });
            }
            else {
                this.value.sort(function (data1, data2) {
                    return _this.multisortField(data1, data2, _this.multiSortMeta, 0);
                });
            }
            if (this.hasFilter()) {
                this._filter();
            }
        }
        this.onSort.emit({
            multisortmeta: this.multiSortMeta
        });
        this.tableService.onSort(this.multiSortMeta);
    }
};
```

**New code:**

```
Table.prototype.sortMultiple = function () {
    const _this = this;
    if (this.multiSortMeta) {
        if (this.lazy) {
            // additional conditions added
            if (this.lazyLoadOnInit || (!this.lazyLoadOnInit && this.initialized)) {
                this.onLazyLoad.emit(this.createLazyLoadMetadata());
            }
        } else if (this.value) {
            if (this.customSort) {
                this.sortFunction.emit({
                    data: this.value,
                    mode: this.sortMode,
                    multiSortMeta: this.multiSortMeta
                });
            } else {
                this.value.sort(function (data1, data2) {
                    return _this.multisortField(data1, data2, _this.multiSortMeta, 0);
                });
            }
            if (this.hasFilter()) {
                this._filter();
            }
        }
        this.onSort.emit({
            multisortmeta: this.multiSortMeta
        });
        this.tableService.onSort(this.multiSortMeta);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was because of `this.cdRef.detectChanges();` Here is why
loadList is binded to `(onLazyLoad)="loadList($event)"` in HTML.

PrimeNg calls that event every time when paging, sorting, and filtering happens. So, when we are loading and adding sorting events it keeps calling. And Angular change detection also called every time, that leads to error `ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

```
loadList($event: any = {}) {
this.cars1 = [
  {
    vin: "a1653d4d",
    brand: "VW",
    year: 1998,
    color: "White",
    price: 10000
  },
  {
    vin: "ddeb9b10",
    brand: "Mercedes",
    year: 1985,
    color: "Green",
    price: 25000
  }
];
this.cdRef.detectChanges(); // this is the issue
```

}

modified

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.cols = [
  { field: "vin", header: "Vin" },
  { field: "year", header: "Year" },
  { field: "brand", header: "Brand" },
  { field: "color", header: "Color" }
  ];

this.multiSortMeta = [
  { field: "year", order: 1 },
  { field: "brand", order: -1 }
];
 this.loadList();
}

loadList($event: any = {}) {
this.cars1 = [
  {
    vin: "a1653d4d",
    brand: "VW",
    year: 1998,
    color: "White",
    price: 10000
  },
  {
    vin: "ddeb9b10",
    brand: "Mercedes",
    year: 1985,
    color: "Green",
    price: 25000
  }
];
// this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
```

The bottom line is `this.cdRef.detectChanges();` need to be used carefully and smartly in anywhere in the application if you are using it.

[updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-p-table-multisort-sjfwsp)

Comment: The `loadList` was called using timeout to simulate API call in my stackblitz link.It works if `loadList()` is directly called but with timeout, it goes in loop. Please try and check.

Comment: updated the same stackblitz. You can call change detection when you are sure about it. Well, that was the issue here, even if API call is there you can call form there, just don't put change detection in that method. It should work without that, on primeNG example they never use that.

Comment: Check my updated stackblitz. Calling the method with settimeout and returning data with settimeout are different scenarios. Also if the `sortMode` is changed from `multiple` to `single` the `loadList` is never called by the table due to `lazyLoadOnInit` flag set to `false`. But if `sortMode` is set to `multiple` the `loadList` is called which it should not. Do check the console.